# woocommerce using full size images, resized, for thumbnails

Tags: wordpress, file, woocommerce, size, thumbnails

I have an up to date install of wordpress and woocommerce using a pretty simple, customized theme.

I recently noticed that woocommerce is not calling thumbnail images for catalog pages, the cart, anywhere.. i hadn't noticed earlier because everything looks OK. For example: the cart displays 32x32px thumbnails, but is merely re-sizing the original image (1000x10000px) down to 32x32 instead of calling a smaller file such as the 150x150px thumbnails. it seems to be doing this anywhere a smaller image is used and my main catalog page is almost 40mb which is ridiculous- it should only weigh 1.5 or 2mb...

if you're feeling frisky, the 40mb catalog page is at superfly5000.com/collections/    (NSFW!!!)

Both woocommerce and wordpress image settings are set to 150x150 and 300x300. WC single product images and WP large size images are set to 0x0 so it will call the original image.

I have regenerated thumbnails and am about to convert all my PNG's to JPG's to save some weight but I really don't want to lose transparencies..

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable the hard-crop option for thumbnails, [more info](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/adding-product-images-and-galleries/#section-4).

Answer (score 0):

resolved: cool thanks,Vikas, the hard crop wasn't the issue but the snippet at the bottom of the page (https://docs.woothemes.com/document/adding-product-images-and-galleries/#section-4)- manually calling image sizes from the functions.php and regenerating thumbnails apparently did the trick. for some reason WC wasn't using it's own image sizes settings- i don't know why.

Comment: Glad to know you got it working, but it should have worked after enabling the hard crop, did you regenerate thumbnails after that?

Comment: Yeah, I regenerated thumbnails after everything i tried- so three or four times including after adding the snippet.